# Buffering Standard Output (STDOUT)

Tags: stdout, buffering, unbuffered

By default, is STDOUT unbuffered? If not what is the type of its default buffering

Thanks

Comment: In what language/environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't give a language, but assuming that you're using C's stdio functions (`fopen()` etc.) or a language that uses these (and most do, for portability reasons):

**It depends on the underlying C runtime library.**

Most libraries will try to detect whether STDOUT is connected to a terminal, and avoid buffering if so, and perform block buffering (e.g. my Linux system buffers 8Kb at a time) if not.

Comment: Pretty sure this is wrong; `stdout` is typically line-buffered when connected to a terminal, not unbuffered. When all your outputs end in a newline, the difference is irrelevant, but if you're outputting without newlines (say, showing a "progress bar" by outputting a dot at a time), it will be buffered. Explicit calls to `fflush` would be needed to output partial lines on demand, or you'd use `setvbuf` to change the buffering mode for the `FILE*` in general.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: You're right, please edit to add this.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: By default STDOUT is usually unbuffered. If this is a problem for you, there is `fflush(stdout);` but that is *rarely needed*

Comment: Again, as noted on accepted answer, `stdout` is typically line buffered when connected to a terminal, and block buffered otherwise. No common C runtime I'm aware of makes it unbuffered by default.